# Pagination data disappears when using paginate() with json serialization functions in Laravel 9

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent, pagination, laravel-9

I'm using paginate with *append()* and *makeHidden()* together and losing the pagination data in the process.

With this code

```
$discussionsJson = Discussion::orderBy('last_reply_at','DESC')
    ->paginate(10)
    ->toJson();
```

I'm getting a json that looks like this:

```
{
  "current_page": XX,
  "data": [
    { bunch }, { of } ,{ discussions}
  ],
  "next_page_url": XX,
  "path": XX,
  "per_page": XX,
  "prev_page_url": XX,
  "to": XX,
  "total": XX
}
```

However, when I add *append()* and/or *makeHidden()* like so:

```
$discussionsJson = Discussion::orderBy('last_reply_at','DESC')
    ->paginate(10)
    ->append(['creator_info','thread_preview'])
    ->makeHidden(['category', 'post'])
    ->toJson();
```

I lose the pagination info and the outcome becomes this:

```
[
  { bunch }, { of }, { discussions}
]
```

Am I doing something wrong?
Is there a way for me to use *append()* and *makeHidden()* and still keep the pagination data?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `->paginate` _after_ appending and hiding?

Comment: Yes, I get an error. it doesn't want me to use append() because it's not a collection. But if I use get() before that, then paginate() gets angry at me for using it on a collection. So it seems like paginate should go first.

Comment: it might be that `append` and `makeHidden`, since they are Collection methods, are returning the Collection not the Paginator instance ... you could save the Paginator instance to a variable, call `append` and `makeHidden` then return the Paginator variable